# B-screw hitting derailleur hanger

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have a Schwinn Super Sport circa 1966, that came to me as a single speed, so I have never seen a derailleur on it. When I put this SunTour derailleur on it - mid 70s I think, came off a Peugeot - the b-screw hits the Schwinn's derailleur hanger body, not the b-screw stop, as you can see in the picture. The stop seems way further forward on the Schwinn than the Peugeot. However, a modern Shimano XT derailleur seems to fit the Schwinn fine . . . I just was hoping for something  approximately period appropriate. What's going on here? Are the different style derailleur hangers? How can I know what derailleurs will fit the Schwinn?

Here's the mismatch:
[image: schwinn and suntour mismatch?]

I can rotate it so it hits the stop, but the derailleur position looks like it would not work, the b-screw is all the way out, not really hitting the stop dead-on, and the derailleur cage is hitting the seat stay:

[image: mismatch part 2]

However, this Deore XT derailleur seems to have a longer or slightly further-out b-screw that hits properly. I haven't put a chain on it to check, but this looks like it would work. So I want something that works like this, but is from the 60s-80s, 10-speed road era.

[image: why does this work?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research it seems that in 1966, Schwinn was using Huret dropouts, which have a different configuration than modern derailleur hangers, which are based on a Campagnolo design. So the options are to get a Huret derailleur, or make an adapter like [this one made from a washer](http://bronzegears.blogspot.com/2008/11/schwinn-sports-tourer-build-drivetrain.html) or look at [this thread](http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/853703-huret-dropouts-derailleur-options.html) for some other options.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a high end Schwinn frame of that era it was meant to be used with a Campy NR derailluer that did not have a b-screw adjustment. See the back of one 
here:

http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=30033&g2_serialNumber=2[image]

The suntour slant-parallelogram derailluer was actually a technological innovation at the time.

However, the more I look at it, the more it looks to me like the dropout might
have been machined in some way. My campy equipped bike from that era has the stop at roughly perpendicular to the slot for the axle in the dropout.